# ¿uso del módulo Shapely (python) para determinar geometrías a partir de un txt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

hola me presentan una matriz de n elementos que equivale a las cordenadas "x" y "y" de un polígono irregular.como uso el modulo shapely? a partir de un archivo txt. Ya que me gustaria poder graficar cualquier tipo de poligono irregular que tenga en estos archivos.

¿Cómo podría graficar un polígono en Python? Me dan ciertas coordenadas, puedo abrir el archivo y graficar sus vértices pero ¿Cómo los puedo unir?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data=pd.read_csv('poligono.txt',header=1,delim_whitespace=True)
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
x=data.iloc[:,0]
y=data.iloc[:,1]
#print(data)
plt.plot(x,y,"ro")
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
```

poligono.txt contiene:

```
 x     y
 4     7
 2     1
 3    -3
-3    -5
-1    -2
-6     2
```

Ejemplo de como debería quedar el polígono

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El título no guarda relación con la pregunta. Yo lo habría titulado "Cómo representar un polígono en matplotlib" o similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No necesitas el módulo Shapely, para lo que estás preguntando. Matplotlib te da las herramientas. En concreto, puedes usar `matplotlib.pyplot.fill()` para dibujar/rellenar polígonos dados por sus vértices como es tu caso.

Por cierto, que tienes un error al leer el fichero, pues pones `headers=1`, lo que causa que se salte el primer par de datos.

Mira este ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import io

# Para no depender de ficheros externos, incluyo como cadena
# Los datos del fichero en cuesitón y uso io.StringIO() para simular
# que la cadena es un fichero
poligonotxt = """ x     y
 4     7
 2     1
 3    -3
-3    -5
-1    -2
-6     2"""

# Lectura de datos
data=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(poligonotxt),delim_whitespace=True)

# Pintar los vértices, en rojo
plt.plot(data.x, data.y,"ro")

# Pintar el polígono, en amarillo, borde negro
plt.fill(data.x, data.y, "yellow", edgecolor="black", linewidth=1)
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")

# Pintar los ejes pasando por (0,0)
plt.axhline(0, color='black', linewidth=0.5)
plt.axvline(0, color='black', linewidth=0.5)
```

[image: Resultado]

Comment: gracias! este codigo lo eh probado y  me ha sido de gran utilidad! ciertamente no es necesario el uso del shapely aunque me gustaria conocer este, es que tengo algunas formas que hasta cierto punto pueden a llegar a ser muy curvas conoces de algún tutorial de shapely que me sirva? y gracias por la nota del header..